How to mark part of pattern as constant
How can I mark part of pattern as constant using IMask?
Consider the following example:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <input type="text" id="inputField" value="3455435345">
  </form>

  <script>
    var masked = IMask(
      document.getElementById('inputField'), {
        mask: '+{345}(000)000-00-00', // expected: +345(345)543-53-45 | actual: +345(543)534-5
        lazy: false
      }
    );
  </script>
</body>

</html>



When page loading the input field filled with value +345(543)534-5, but I expect +345(345)543-53-45.
How can I achieve this?

Why would you expect a result with 13 digits, when your input has only 10?

@ScottHunter Because if you modify the input base value to "1234567890", then it will print "+345(123)456-78-90".

I ended up to modify the backend to set also the country prefix "3453455435345" for the input. Which in this case the IMask view component loads the data correctly. But it is just weird.
